# Why are spin-1/2 particles the simplest particles?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, particle-physics, quantum-spin, fermions, dirac-equation

Paul Dirac, in his interview with Friedrich Hund, mentioned that it was to his surprise that his equation automatically incorporated spin. He said that he thought the simplest theory, for which he was formulating his equation, would be that of a spinless particle (a scalar) and that there would have been a more complicated theory for those particles with spin but as it turns out the simplest particle is that with a spin-1/2. I don't understand why this is so.

Comment: Do you know what Dirac equation and Rarita–Schwinger equation is or why is it used for?

Comment: I am familiar with the Dirac equation, how and why it was formulated and how it came to be in its "four-dimensional" form but I am not familiar with the Rarita–Schwinger equation.

Comment: Rarita–Schwinger equation is the relativistic field equation of spin-3/2 fermions

Comment: I see. How does that answer my question though?

Comment: I think it comes down to the Dirac equation being a first order and the Klein-Gordon equation being a second order equation, but "simple" and "complicated" are not really words with objective meanings, so this question is going to be a guessing game.

Comment: There is a sense in which spin-1/2 is the "simplest particle".  That is because it is the fundamental rep of the rotation group SU(2).  All other spin particles can be built as a linear combinations of a product of spin-1/2 kets.  Spin-0 for example:  |0,0>=(1/sqrt(2))(|1/2,1/2>|1/2,-1/2>-|1/2,-1/2>|1/2,1/2>).  Particles  of other spins (and presumably Dirac like equations of other spins) look more complicated when built with lots of spin-1/2 constituents,  each of which must be rotated separately to rotate the whole particle.